# Limit involving greatest integer function and modulus

Tags: calculus, limits

Can anybody help me with this limit? 
I think the answer should be $0$ as $0$ to the power $1$ should be $0$ but it doesn't match with the book's answer.

$$ \lim_{x\to 0} |x|^{\lfloor\cos{x}\rfloor}$$

Comment: Please include the information in the post. Preferably in typed form not as an image.

Comment: I am sorry but I don't currently have access to a pc and its the best I can do from my phone. :(

Comment: I will try to edit it for you. Please comment

Comment: Please edit it.Thank you

Comment: Is it the floor or the ceiling function for $\cos$

Comment: Floor function The one which represents the greatest integer less than or equal to x

Comment: So the edit is right and $\lfloor\cos{x}\rfloor=0$ for $x\neq 0$ in a small neighborhood of $0$ and $\lfloor\cos{0}\rfloor=1$

Comment: @Karan Singh As it turns out your question does neither have a greatest integer function, nor a modulus. Could you suggest a better title, possibly with floor function as exponent and absolute value?

Comment: @marwalix there is no small neighborhood around 0 for which $\cos(x)=1$, there is exactly the one value, namely 0. Edit: sry, as it turns out I have misunderstood you and you had it right already.

Comment: My question does have the modulus over x and the floor function over cos x.

Comment: @Lykos I claim there is a neighborhood of $0$ where if we exclude $0$ we have $0\leq \cos x\lt 1$ and therefore $\lfloor\cos{x}\rfloor=0$ because if we are too far we have for example $\lfloor\cos{(\pi/2+\epsilon)}\rfloor=-1$

Comment: @Karan Sing You are right, I am just not used to these names, I was not aware that you could use modulus as absolute value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}|x|^{\lfloor\cos{x}\rfloor}\\
\lim_{x\rightarrow0}\lfloor\cos{x}\rfloor=0\\
y^0 = 1
$$
The floor function means this is a special case... for values of x>0 it will have the limit 1 but for x=1 it will have the value 0. This means that the limit is 1 but the value of the function at x=0 is 0 as there is a step in your function.

Comment: cos x is within a greatest integer function I. E. the box function

Comment: do you mean the "round up" function, which would be written as ⌈x⌉?

Answer (score 1):

So  the edit is right and $\lfloor\cos{x}\rfloor=0$ for $x\neq 0$ in a small neighborhood of $0$ and $\lfloor\cos{0}\rfloor=1$.

One has $|x|^{\lfloor\cos{x}\rfloor}=1$ is a constant function for $x\neq 0$ and the limit you're looking for is $1$