# The definition of limit

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, definition

When we take the limit towards somthing, do we never actully attain the number?

For example,

[Limit involving greatest integer function and modulus](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290176/limit-involving-greatest-integer-function-and-modulus?rq=1)

They seams to exploit that we never hit zero and that they thus have,

$\lim_{x \rightarrow0} \lfloor \cos x \rfloor=0$

Comment: we don't have to, but we may. The constant sequence $a_n= b$ converges to $b$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes we do, sometimes we don't. We don't require non-attainment, we only require that we can get as close as we want to that value as long as we go "close enough" to the limit value.

If $\lim_{x \rightarrow a} f(x) = b$, it means that if I ask, "can you make $f(x)$ get "this" close to $b$?" You say "yes, I can" and then provide an $x$ that is "close enough" to $a$ such that $f(x)$ is that close to $b$, no matter how close I asked you to get $f(x)$ to $b$.

That is,
for every $\epsilon > 0$, there exists a $\delta > 0$ such that if $|x-a|< \delta$, then $|f(x)-b| < \epsilon$.

Note that here in relation to the above informal explanation "$\epsilon$" represents how close I asked you to get to the function, and "$\delta$" represents your response, "I just need to be this close to $a$."

Comment: nothing that I said implies that we never attain it.

Answer (score 0):

Any careful epsilon-delta definition of limit includes an assertion of the form

$$0\lt|x-a|\lt\delta\implies|f(x)-L|\lt\epsilon$$

The pertinent thing here is the opening "$0\lt$" in the assertion.  This allows for a function to have a limit at a point $x=a$ without being continuous at that point. The OP's example, $f(x)=\lfloor\cos x\rfloor$, is an example.

It's worth looking closely at whatever calculus or real analysis text you used for learning about limits.  It would be interesting to know of any that allow for $|x-a|=0$.